# How to display the output "Hello" (with the quotes)?

Tags: c

I have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
   printf("Hello");
}
```

The output will be `Hello`. But I want the output to be displayed as `"Hello"`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Just escape with the backslash the double quotes literal:

```
 printf("\"Hello\"");
```

Answer (score 5):

By using its ascii code! (just kidding... Escape it :-) )

It's code 34, so 22 in hexadecimal or 42 in octal. Is it enough?

```
printf("\x22Hello\x22");
printf("\n");
printf("\042Hello\042");
```

Now we will go for the over-overkill:

```
printf("%cHello%c", '"', '"');
```

We let the `printf` "compose" our string and we pass it two `char`s as parameters. The two chars are the `"`, but the quote used for char is single-quote, so no problems :-)

Comment: seriously? :D why not use  single quote twice?

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in backslash-escaped quotes:

```
 printf("\"Hello\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
printf("\"Hello\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("\"%s\"", "hello");
```

or

```
#define prints(x) printf("\"%s\"", (x))
prints("hello");
```